# Deleting borders from merged layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, merge, delete, borders

I merged more layers together but I need to delete these borders. It is possible?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the *Dissolve* tool, it will likely do what you are aiming for.

Comment: @Matt i suppose your comment is a valid answer

Comment: @Taras I am fairly confident this is a duplicate, which is why I didn't make a proper answer, but at the time of commenting I had no time to look for a relevant link.